# Python: findall with xmlns prefix

Tags: python, xml

I have multiple XML documents to parse, all with the same Element names but each document has it's own unique namespace.

How do I extract the namespace on its own, so I can include it as a prefix for my "findall" loops?

For example, here's one of XML files...

```
<ColorCorrectionCollection xmlns="urn:ASC:CDL:v1.2">
    <ColorCorrection id="af/af-123/neutral">
          <SOPNode>
               <Slope>2 1 1</Slope>
               <Offset>0 0 0</Offset>
               <Power>1 1 1</Power>
          </SOPNode>
          <SATNode>
               <Saturation>1</Saturation>
          </SATNode>
    </ColorCorrection>
    <ColorCorrection id="af/af-123/beauty">
          <SOPNode>
               <Slope>1.5 1.2 0.9</Slope>
               <Offset>0 0 0</Offset>
               <Power>1 1 1</Power>
          </SOPNode>
          <SATNode>
               <Saturation>0.8</Saturation>
          </SATNode>
    </ColorCorrection>
```

Here's example code to start...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.findall("ColorCorrection"):
    # the above won't find anything,
    # as I need specify "{urn:ASC:CDL:v1.2}" as prefix.
    # how can I GET "{urn:ASC:CDL:v1.2}" into a variable?
```

Comment: There are various Python modules in use for parsing XML, so please mention which one you're using in your question so people don't have to guess.

Comment: PM 2Rings, maybe it's xml.etree.ElementTree because Dan uses namespace ET, I guess. But for clarity, it's better to be told concretely.

Comment: Correct, I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you actually want to do, but I guess:

- you use xml.etree.ElementTree,
- and you want to extract `xmlns` value from the variable `root`.

`root.tag` includes a string like `'{urn:ASC:CDL:v1.2}ColorCorrectionCollection'` and how about using the following code?

```
root.tag[:root.tag.find('}') + 1]
# => '{urn:ASC:CDL:v1.2}'
```

Comment: FYI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953761/accessing-xmlns-attribute-with-python-elementree